# Oracle domain number to double issue

Tags: java, hashmap

I'd like to add the number as it is `72001000.24` without scientific notation (`7.200100024E7`).
I could use `DecimalFormat` to format it, but it returns a string, when I put it into map I will need to convert it to double which gives the number with scientific notation again. How to resolve this?

```
Map<String, Double> totalMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
oracle.jbo.domain.Number temp = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(72001000.24);
totalMap.put("str", temp.doubleValue());
// enter code here
```

Comment: Q: Why Double?  Why not [java.lang.Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)?

Comment: The "scientific notation" isn't part of the `double`.  A `double` is just a number.  The formatting is only introduced when you print it out, not when you store it.  This question is essentially meaningless.

Comment: I understand your point. Why did temp.doubleValue() return 7.200100024E7? I'm debugging existing code, I don't want to introduce new bugs, so I want to use Double.

Comment: Oh, it returned the correct number.  But when you printed it out, it was FORMATTED in scientific notation.  In other words, the scientific notation is not a feature of the number itself, but a feature of the means of printing.